# Upload in Google API and Dropbox SDK

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-storage, dropbox-api, google-api-client, resume-upload

I already have an upload function in Google API and Dropbox API, but the problem is it can only upload small files like images but it cant upload big files like videos. Please help what do I need to add in the code.

This is my code in Google

[image][image]

This is my code in Dropbox
[image]

Please help..

Comment: What happens? What output/error do you get?

Comment: no error. but can only upload small files like images. i want to download big files like videos..